# Description wont show, and the thumbnail wont either

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    emb = discord.Embed(color=0xda70d6,title = 'Issue with command', discription = 'Using the correct commands is helpful, if you dont know them use "_help"')
    emb.set_author(name = 'Alert', icon_url='https://i.pinimg.com/474x/60/5e/ac/605eac3124c4885e067002cdd4ff684a.jpg')
    emb.set_thumbnail('https://library.kissclipart.com/20191119/ww/kissclipart-help-icon-help-and-support-icon-92018307fcf5c4fa.png')
    emb.set_footer('If you have any questions just DM the onwer Saly_Derek#0031 or Co-Owner Salty_Troye#0540')
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

When I use the command in my console I get this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 58, in on_command_error
   emb.set_thumbnail('https://library.kissclipart.com/20191119/ww/kissclipart-help-icon-help-and-support-icon-92018307fcf5c4fa.png')
TypeError: set_thumbnail() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

But I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Do not post [screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), paste the relevant code required for a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly into your post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information *as text*. You can ``code format`` both code and console text. Consider to take another look at the [ask] and [mre] help pages.

Comment: ok sorry working on it now

Comment: [According to the docs, ``set_thumbnail`` only takes the ``url`` parameter as a *named* argument.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.set_thumbnail). That's ``emb.set_thumbnail(url='https://…')``.

Comment: so what would i have to change, sorry im kinda new to the embed stuff, but im trying my best to learn. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: With regards to your most recent edit, I'd recommend a look at [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/5763413)

Comment: i figured it out, thanks @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Thank you @blackbrandt that helped and figured my problem out!'

Comment: If you figured out your issue, please post it as an answer in case others run into the same issue. Saying "Thanks I figured it out" is not useful to anyone.

Comment: Yes i will now, this is my first time using stackoverflows. i will keep that in mind! where do i post it? in comments?

Comment: There is an answer box right below the comment field. See also [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: ok thanks @MisterMiyagi doing it now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my issue, this works 100%. My issue was for emb.set_thumbnail I never had "url = 'link'"

````
@client.event 
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    emb = discord.Embed(color=0xda70d6,title = 'Issue with command', description = f'''using commands properly is helpful. Use command "_help"''') 
    emb.set_author(name = 'Alert', icon_url = 'https://i.pinimg.com/474x/60/5e/ac/605eac3124c4885e067002cdd4ff684a.jpg')
    emb.set_thumbnail(url =  'https://library.kissclipart.com/20191119/ww/kissclipart-help-icon-help-and-support-icon-92018307fcf5c4fa.png')
    emb.set_footer(text = f'If you have any questions just DM the onwer Saly_Derek#0031 or Co-Owner Salty_Troye#0540')
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)```
````